# Why is "ass" considered obscene?

Tags: idioms, vocabulary, slang, offensive-language

Spam filters replace [obscene "Ass" for "butt"](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/technology/8528672.stm)

Meanwhile, in literature, newspaper articles, forum posts, sayings, proverbs,  etc. I am encountering many more expressions with *ass* but not with *butt*.

Why is *ass* considered obscene?

What is the difference between *ass* and *butt*?

Comment: _Sorry to butt in on you_.

Comment: Donkeys are not obscene.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I am not sure whether I understood correctly your comment nut your editing is the most valuable for me feedback

Comment: Note that ass is only considered obscene in North America. In Britain, it is considered a "weak, sad word" (-Terry Pratchett), as it an American sanitization of arse, which is the English vulgar word for backside.

Comment: @vgv8: I wrote a sentence where the word doesn't have an obscene meaning.

Comment: *Ass* could also be quite an old-fashioned insult in British English, something that you might have read in *Swallows & Amazons*, and would actually refer to the animal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why is ass considered obscene?

When *ass* is used to refer to the animal, it's generally not considered obscene. Some would consider it obscene when referring to the human posterior, or more likely, when used as an epithet for a boorish or stupid person. *Asshole* in my view is considered even more obscene.

The "why?" question is pretty subjective. Why is any word considered obscene?  It's just the way the word developed and societal convention.

I believe in the spectrum of obscenities, even as an epithet it's not *that* obscene. In my opinion, a filter which replaces the word with *butt* is too stringent.

> What is the difference between ass and butt?

When referring to anatomy, there's little difference. Each word has other senses, however. An *ass* can refer to the sure-footed animal smaller than a horse with big ears. It can also mean a pompous fool or be used as slang for sexual intercourse *(get some ass)*.

*Butt* has many other senses. It can be the part of the trunk of a tree nearest the roots, the victim of ridicule *(butt of your jokes)*, thick end of a handle or stock of a rifle/pistol, the end of a cigarette, or a type of joint (carpentry, not the other type of cigarette.)

*Butt* can also be used as a verb, to place end to end, to lie adjacent, or to strike or shove against/in between, (to butt in line.)

Comment: +1 "Why is any word considered obscene?" My sister refuses to say "butt" when referencing anatomy. She says "bottom."

Comment: About the other meanings of *ass* — AFAIK, the "pompous fool"(?) meaning ("Don't be an ass") comes from the donkey, while the sexual meaning ("get some ass") comes from anatomy.

Answer (score 3):

I will answer to the second question.

The words have different meanings; leaving out what the words mean when they are used as verbs, these are the definitions of the words:

> butt /bət/
>   noun
>   the person or thing at which criticism or humor, typically unkind, is directed: *his singing is the butt of dozens of jokes*.
>   • (usually *butts*) an archery or shooting target or range.
>   • a mound on or in front of which a target is set up for archery or shooting.
>
> noun
>   a push or blow, typically given with the head: he would follow up with a butt from his head.
>
> noun
>   1. (also butt end) the thicker end, especially of a tool or a weapon: *a rifle butt*.
>      • the square end of a plank or plate meeting the end or side of another, as in the side of a ship.
>      • the thicker or hinder end of a hide used for leather.
>   2. (also butt end) the stub of a cigar or a cigarette: *the ashtray was crammed with cigarette butts*.
>   3. informal the buttocks.
>      • the anus.
>   4. the trunk of a tree, especially the part just above the ground.

> ass /æs/
>   noun
>   1. a hoofed mammal of the horse family with a braying call, typically smaller than a horse and with longer ears.
>       • Genus Equus, family Equidae: E. africanus of Africa, which is the ancestor of the domestic ass or donkey, and E. hemionus of Asia.
>      • (in general use) a donkey.
>   2. (informal) a foolish or stupid person: *that ass of a young man*.

Comment: As a side note, I will write the meaning of _to butt in_: _take part in a conversation or activity, or enter somewhere, without being invited or expected_. That is the meaning of _sorry to butt in on you._

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you know the different meanings of ass. For the vulgar meaning it comes from the reconstructed Proto-Indo-European "**Orse**" which means (“**backside**, **buttocks**, **butt**”). In this meaning it's widely used in North America.

Note: Also it has some other word origins.

Comment: I did not write that I did not know. But I did not know that "ass" is considered obscene while "butt" not. In my exp the "ass" is more widely used and in any spectrum of contexts and  situations